# codeigniter working fine on local but not on web server. 404 Error

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter is working fine on local server but not on web server.

I used `XAMPP` for the development on local.

I am using Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9 for Microsoft Windows.

**404 error page of codeigniter is not loading. Url is loadind 404 error page of the server. I have removed all** `.htacces` **rewrite rules of root directory and included** `index.php`. **Still it isn't working.**

Searched alot but couldn't find right solution

Directory for codeigniter folders(site, application, system)

is

```
mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/
```

Base url in *mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/application/config/config.php*

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site/';
```

In *mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/application/.htaccess*

```
Deny from all
```

Envoirment set in index.php (*mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site/index.php*)

```
switch (dirname(__FILE__)) {
        case 'http://mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site':
            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
        break;

        default:
            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
        break;
    }
          $system_path = '../system';
          $application_folder = '../application';
```

In *mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site/.htaccess*

```
               <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                           Options +FollowSymLinks
                           RewriteEngine on
                           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
              </IfModule>
```

In *mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/application/config/routes.php*

```
           $route['default_controller'] = "page";
           $route['404_override'] = 'page';
           $route['article/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'article/index/$1/$2';
```

I am giving url *mysite/demo/test/site* and
 **its giving 404 error page of web server not of codeigniter**

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Can you access the site with `index.php` included? e.g. `mysite/demo/test/site/index.php`

Comment: No, I tried that too.

Comment: Try `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Comment: I tried every way where path is involved after that I have posted the question.

Comment: is your host GoDaddy?

Comment: hostcats Bangalore, India.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I contacted my host. They said that there was a problem  in php handler.

Apart from this IIS doesn't read `.htaccess` file, Instead I make a file `web.config` and replace with `.htaccess` in *mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site/*

Content of `web.config` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Now the website is up and running. **Thanks for the support**.

Comment: I wasted my whole day, and finally find the solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I'll go for an answer.

Check your project root directory if you have the `.htaccess` file and if you have access to the server, might as well check too if `mod_rewrite` is enabled *(assuming you are using Apache)*. This might be an URL rewrite issue.

**EDIT 1**

Ok now I see you have a `.htaccess` file in there. How about the `<Directory>` directives in your *httpd.conf* or is this setup via `<VirtualHost>`?

**EDIT 2**

Try changing your `.htaccess` with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I didn't touch anything like that. Simply made a website in codeigniter and uploading it to web server and using **Parallels Plesk Panel**

Comment: I don't have actual experience of using Parallels Plesk Panel,but as I see it there seems to be wrong in here. See this: `case 'http://mysite/httpdocs/demo/test/site` that should not be the URL. What is your domain name for this project? In local it might work, but not in live.

Comment: Plesk uses IIS server. Therefore I have removed `.htaccess` thing.

Comment: If that will be your domain then your `base_url` should be `http://karigarifashions.com/`. Is this domain the one binded in your httpdocs?