# Codeigniter URL working locally but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a silly error somewhere. Locally I've been using:

```
localhost:8080/project/index.php/Welcome/emailsend/Name/PersonEmail/EmailMessage
```

Where Name, PersonEmail and EmailMessage are parameters passed via the url. Now locally everything worked fine. The function emailsend would return something. Note here my base URL was in my config file was empty.

I've now uploaded my code to a server and I'm looking to see if this url works:

```
mysubdomain.domainname.com/index.php/Welcome/emailsend/Name/PersonEmail/EmailMessage
```

I now get a 404 Error page not found. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: have you read this : https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155912/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630669/codeigniter-working-fine-on-local-but-not-on-web-server-404-error

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your codeIgniter config file and to change the site and the base URLs.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html or you can go to  application/config/config.php and changing them manually.