# 404 - File or directory not found. Codeigniter on windows server

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, live

i uploaded my codignter website to a windows server.And home page is working fine,but all other links and pages showing

Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Allow from all
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

its works on Linux server 
please help.

Comment: Check your path and print your path and run in the browser.

Comment: i checked it,path is correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630669/codeigniter-working-fine-on-local-but-not-on-web-server-404-error

Comment: Welcome Bro....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a file `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```